# Delete own question which is a downvote magnet?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, questions

I have a [question with imho multiple good answers (at least for C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839466/reading-using-modifying-uninitialised-variables-guarantees), dealing with an often made assertion by answerers on C and C++ questions. Because of those answers I'm reluctant to delete it.

Now, even though I clarified the question following advice in comments (Yes, I was a bit too vague at the start), I still get a nagging trickle of downvotes and no upvotes.

Should I delete it to remove that annoyance, or just accept that I will forever collect more downvotes there?
Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Oh it just has 9 down votes. Now wait and see the magic aka the Meta Effect :)

Comment: No need to delete the question, better improve it.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: By now it is already short and to the point. The examples were there from the beginning.

Comment: You can't delete it since it has answers with upvotes. And since there are multiple answers with multiple upvotes, it is likely to help someone else. *Disclaimer: I didn't read the question or answers so going on the vote counts*

Comment: Wasn't me adding that, but saw no reason to remove it.

Comment: Wow, now someone wants to close it as primarily opinion-based. The Meta-effect is becoming scary.

Comment: Be careful when you invoke [God] with your tags, He expects you to have done your research.  I changed it, ought to help.

Comment: @HansPassant: Which is one reason I added neither language-lawyer nor god. So, you think whoever added that called down HIS wrath? Thanks for your help.

Comment: related: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

Comment: Cf. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288327/should-i-delete-my-old-question-which-was-closed-and-gets-downvotes-on-random-da

Comment: Could it be made into a wiki question?

Comment: @Renan That's a mod-only option for some time now, and won't happen...

Answer (score 3):

I like that question. Methinks just re-organize it a bit so that the question is immediately obvious (it's not very clear what you're asking atm), and perhaps avoid phrasing it like some kind of homework or challenge, e.g.:

---

> My understanding of the docs and specs is that any use of uninitialised variables invokes UB, but it's not entirely clear to me that this is the case due to the code examples posted below.
>
> Might anyone be able to chime in on this for C and C++ to clarify what's going on? If possible, with subtle and not so subtle differences or corner cases that might shed further light on the topic?
>
> ```
> [code examples…]
> ```

---

There's also feedback in the comments as to why it's getting down-voted:

[Any guarantees for uninitialised variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839466/any-guarantees-for-uninitialised-variables#comment34841043_22839466)

Comment: FYI: I had already acted on the comments.

Comment: @Deduplicator: perhaps you have, and irrespective of the fact that I actually upvoted the question as interesting, it currently isn't immediately clear what you're asking, not to mention what passes off as a challenge at the very end. So I still think you ought to rephrase it further.

Comment: Rewrote it yet again.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the question to add more information, after reading it, it isn't clear what you're asking, and the fact you got answers is incredible, it also shows you're nearly there with it.
Even though you have edited it, in its current guise, it still isn't obvious what the question is, address this issue and you'll have a much better question.

<s>Of course, you can delete it, but if the answers are helpful to others you are potentially depriving people of that.</s>* Thinking about it though, it's just a meaningless number on a website, in the grand scheme of things, does it matter?

---

*You can't delete it with upvoted answers anyway

Comment: It only matters that I get down-votes from time to time, which make me want to improve or remove it. I stated the question at the start, at the end and in the title, using different words. There are even examples.

Comment: @Deduplicator "Reading / Using / Modifying uninitialised variables: Guarantees?" isn't a good question, I'm sure you can improve it more.