# Should I delete my old question which was closed and gets downvotes on random days

Tags: discussion, questions, unclear

I am referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038939/strange-array-behavior-in-javascript), which is quite old now and was closed right after asking. The reason for closing, was right, ***unclear what you're asking***.

Then later, I edited the question so someone who reads it would understand it. Now it sometimes get downvotes, which makes me feel the question still doesn't fit into Stack Overflow rules or might be a bad question itself.

Maybe even after editing, it's still not clear to understand the question, and thus it might continue to get downvotes.

**Should I delete the question?**
It has got a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039074/3556874), though.

Comment: Looking at your question did not seem to deserve downvoting (personally to me), so I upvoted it. Deleting a question with nice answer is against stackoverflow rules ;)

Comment: While I edited your question it now also has a delete vote. Welcome to the *meta effect*

Comment: thats really a sad effect.. I just raised this on meta, because I felt question was good,

Comment: Your username probably doesn't help things.

Comment: Yeah i changed it for the same resaon  about a week ago

Comment: This one won't help, too.

Comment: I know.. I thought if someone is randomly revenge downvoting me!! Would be nice to hide with other name for a month :P

Comment: Username or not, the *Meta effect* sure did "help things". I'm getting tired of these unnecessary massive upvotes/downvotes for every single question on Meta...

Comment: I m too.. Its became a gamble for people, i dont understand why people go and vote unnecessarily to que raised on meta

Comment: Regarding meta effect, I tend to vote on just about every question I see and understand. If I understand enough to recognize if the question is good or not, I vote accordingly. I assume most people vote that same way. So if I upvoted your question, it's not just because you posted on Meta, it's because your edit made it a good question and I saw a good question when I clicked on the link. Meta may bring attention to a question, whether intentionally or not, which leads to more votes being cast because more people see it, however, individuals cast the votes, not meta as a whole, so it's fair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is now re-opened after my edit and got enough upvotes to give it a positive score.

I flagged for a moderator to ask for a comment clean-up.

Good luck with your question.

Comment: Thank u.. And there are enough votes on the question too.. So someone reading this post please consider not to vote my question, causing meta effect

Comment: You did not explain why he should not delete his question.

Comment: @Joiner No, I didn't because that is up to the OP although my *Good luck* indicates that I'm not sure of the outcome. I assumed the real question was *can this be rescued* which I think was possible if I gave it proper edit before too much of the meta-effect kicked in. I left an answer explaining my action in the hope that would reduce the meta-effect.

Answer (score 2):

When you contribute to the Stack Exchange network, the post becomes a *collaborative effort*.
That's why you should not delete your own posts, mostly if they are questions which contain good answers.
Note that your account might get blocked for this.

Comment: See thats what my question is, if it becomes a dovnvote source for me, why should i keep it just like that.. So basically your answer says, i should just keep getting downvotes from that question, and shouldnt even remove it?

Comment: "Never delete" is far too stringent. You should avoid making any posts which are worthless, and you should correct those which fail to meet the standards. A small number of deleted posts isn't really harmful, and there's no reason to preserve a turd. (I didn't read the specific post, so I have no idea of it's quality.)

Comment: @Deduplicator.. Agree we should avoid making low quality posts.. But if there is a bad poat by me, which got a single downvote immediately, becomes a downvote source, even after i imrove the post.. Just becaause people see the downvotes, and follow the rule, they dont see tge quality is improved or not!! In that case it really becomes paiful, even after improving quality people keep downvoting , since its already a downvoted question..

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz: No argument that a niggling trickle of downvotes is extremely annoying. And that the first impression a post made, especially if it resulted in votes (in whatever direction) often has an unfortunately strong influence even after only the votes remain of it.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't down-vote your question myself but I'm posting this to explain why some people might not consider it such a great question.

While it's now clear what you're asking ("why does JavaScript work differently from other languages such as Java"), it seems like a rather trivial question to me. If JavaScript didn't work differently from Java in a few aspects, it wouldn't be JavaScript, it would be Java, right?

Why can't I drive to work on a ham sandwich? Maybe because it doesn't have wheels, or an engine? These are good answers but that doesn't make the question less trivial.

Comment: Trivial????????

Comment: Yes. In my view, the real question is why would someone a priori assume that JavaScript must behave like Java, and when they discover it doesn't, why would they assume that there is an interesting "why" to that. These are programming language design tradeoffs. The only real answer to such a question is "because the designers of JavaScript thought that would be better".

Comment: Lets not get into technical here on meta, the question here is different, a question regarding a question.. If you have answer to that particular question, feel free to post it there.